# multiple commands from a single button syntax error tkinter python

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, syntax-error

I have a simple gui here with inputs buttons etc, I am trying to run two commands off one button. One command to update the dictionary and one to write to file when I run my code I get an error saying

> NameError: name 'writeToFile' is not defined.

I can't see anything obvious I've missed and it only seems to happen when i call two functions to the button I also tried

```
def combine_funcs(*funcs):
    def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in funcs:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
    return combined_func

self.testButton = Button(self, text = "test", 
                        command = combine_funcs(commando, writeToFile))
```

But it didn't like this either and it said comine_funcs wasnt defined

Any help would be appreciated!

```
from tkinter import * 
import csv

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.output()    


    fL = {}


    def commando(x, y):
        fL.update({x:int(y)})  # Please note that these x and y vars are private to this function.  They are not the x and y vars as defined below.
        print(fL)

    def writeToFile():
        with open('WorkOrderLog.csv', 'w') as f:
            w=csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            #w.writerow("Name" + self.input1.get())
            w.writerow(fL)

    def output(self):     

        input_1 = StringVar()  # Creating the variables that will get the user's input.
        input_2 = StringVar()

        Label(text='Name:').grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5,pady=5)
        self.input1 = Entry(root, textvariable=input_1, width=10)
        self.input1.grid(row=0, column=1,padx=5,pady=5)

        Label(text='Age:').grid(row=1, column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.input2 = Entry(root, textvariable=input_2, width=10)
        self.input2.grid(row=1, column=1,padx=5,pady=5)      

        self.b = Button(text="Two Functions", command=commando)
        self.b.grid(row=4, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.b.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', command=writeToFile)
        self.b.focus_force()

       # self.b = Button(root, text='Submit', command=sequence(commando, writeToFile))
        #self.b.grid(row=4, column=4,padx=5,pady=5)      


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=Tk()
    root.title('Auto Logger')
    root.geometry('1000x100')
    app=App(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `writeToFile` is a function, you must call it as such: `writeToFile()`. Cheers :)

Comment: You have errors everywhere, the first parameter should be self in all your methods, then reference the methods with `self.commando` etc ..  Same for your attributes  `self.fL.update`

Comment: @TemporalWolf - Incorrect. The `combine_funcs` function will handle calling each function.

Comment: @TemporalWolf: He is not trying to call the function; he is trying to pass the function itself to another function.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 when using the combine_funcs method i still get the name error when calling it with the button. Any ideas as to where my error is from?

Comment: As Padraic said, your code is full of errors, largely related to OOP. I recommend Googling some tutorials or other instructional materials to learn about how to properly define a class.

Comment: Why such a complicated solution? Just create a normal function that calls the two functions.

Comment: keep your code simple. Create one function . No need for the for loop. Maybe even a lambda at most.